# Is there a way to auto generate controls on a form from a binding source?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

When I add a binding source to my windows form, is there a quick way to populate the form with all the properties of the bound object?

A drag and drop Field List, similar to that found in many report writers would be good.

Comment: You can drag fields from Data Source Window and drop on form. You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37824444/3110834) helpful.

Comment: So the answer is to use the menu View->Other Windows-> Data Sources. Care to write that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, the [Data Sources Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ckyxa83.aspx) displays the data sources in your project. You can use [Data Source Configuration Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4dd7z6t.aspx) to create and edit data sources from databases, services, or objects.  After creating data sources in your project, you can use the Data Sources window to create data-bound controls in your user interface by dragging items from the window onto a design surface in your project:

- Show [Data Source Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ckyxa83.aspx) from menu View `>` Other Windows `>` Data Sources or by using its shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
- [Add new Data Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx) using Add new Data Source toolbar button in Data Source Window or using menu Project `>` Add New Data Source.
- Open a form and then in Data Source Window [Set the Control to be created](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31ct733b(v=vs.110).aspx) when dragging from the Data Sources Window. 
  If you choose details mode in Data Source Window, for each field of data source a control will be placed on the form. If you choose DataGridView mode, `DataGridView` will be placed on the form.

[image]
[image]