# DataGridView not showing my columns

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have a MySQL connection in C# that supposedly puts the table data into a `DataGridView`, but it has a problem and it makes the rows for every account in my users table in my db, but it doesn't show the actual data. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string connectionString = "Server=mysql.dunkycart.com; Database=dunkycart; Uid=dunkycart; Pwd=rooB-dnK-sqL;"; //Set your MySQL connection string here.
    string query = "SELECT name, username, email FROM users"; // set query to fetch data "Select * from  tabelname"; 
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The issue:
[image: This is the output of the form. I entered the column names manually, btw, so it's not doing that either.]

Comment: You may find this post useful. [Is there a way to auto generate controls on a form from a binding source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165043/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-controls-on-a-form-from-a-binding-source)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `DataSet` instead of `DataTable` so you need to change this:

```
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

To this:

```
adapter.Fill(ds,"tbl");
```

Or you can use a [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DataSet`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: It displays now but it displays an extra blank row that's not in my table. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Wiooo Yes. Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `False` in `DataGridView`'s Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just found a fix. What I had to do is set the DataPropertyName for each column in the DataGridView to the corresponding column in the db table.